# Removing repeated string values in print

Tags: python-2.7

I would like to count different universities from which the mail was sent for which i used the following code:

```
fname = raw_input('Enter the file name: ')
try:
    fhan = open(fname)
except:
print 'File cannot be opened:', fname
count = 0
sum = 0
for i in fhan:
    if i.startswith('From'):
        x=i.find('@')
        y=i.find(' ',x)
        str1=i[x+1:y].strip()
        print str1
        count=count+1
print count
```

The final output gives me the handles but can i remove the repeated ones, if i print uct.ac.za it shouldnot print and count again

link for file: www.py4inf.com/code/mbox-short.txt

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) Please edit into your question: Do you want to suppress immediate repetitions (just compare to previous) or all of them (necessitating to somehow remember *all* already printed)?

Answer (score 1):

You can append the handles in a list instead of printing it. And then convert that list in a `set`. In a set there are no repeated elements so you will get the a set of unique universities. And Finally, you can iterate through the set and print the universities.

For `count` you can use the `len` function that will count the universities in the set.

This is the modified code:-

```
fname = raw_input('Enter the file name: ')
try:
    fhan = open(fname)
except:
    print 'File cannot be opened:', fname
universities = []
for i in fhan:
    if i.startswith('From'):
        x=i.find('@')
        y=i.find(' ',x)
        str1=i[x+1:y].strip()
        universities.append(str1)
universities = set(universities)
for i in universities:
    print i
print len(universities)
```